# Require PHP file from URL

Tags: php, require

When I writting code on PHP, I need to require or import .PHP files, containing classes and functions need for me. For example `

```
<?php require("ffmpeg.php"); ?>
```

May I require PHP file, which I have no on root directory, but it stored on website, for example `

```
<?php require("http://example.com/ffmpeg.php"); ?>
```

If it was real, please help me with this question.

Comment: Yes, using the [allow_url_include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) config. Very dangerous, not recommended

Comment: Look at your php.ini and make sure allow_url_include is set to 1.

Comment: Depending on the serverconfiguration (version of PHP) . allow_url_include => Available since PHP 5.2.0. Deprecated as of PHP 7.4.0.

Comment: What is the reason why you need this? As @AlonEitan pointed out this is not recommended.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld, could be worth adding that fact to the duplicate (i.e. deprecated in 7.4)

Comment: The best option would be forgo trying to pull the files into your server and build an API that executes the functionality you desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use file_get_contents and then you will need to write the contents to a file or you could directly execute using eval.

```
 //option 1 save to file
$contents = file_get_contents("http://example.com/ffmpeg.php");
file_put_content("yourphpfilename.php", $contents);

//option 2 get and execute
$contents = file_get_contents("http://example.com/ffmpeg.php");
eval($contents);
```

Comment: This is extremely dangerous to try.  Also if the remote system has PHP installed it will only return the result of the script and not the code itself.

Comment: @NigelRen I 100% agree and that is something the OP should consider if deciding to move forward with implementing this sort of functionality.